# Can't retrieve data from a global variable in javascript/nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to put data into an object. Although this object in loop has value, this object out of the loop hasn't value (empty). I had instance object global variable `obj`. What's wrong with me?

p.s : findOne is a mongoose's method. (mongodb).

```
var obj = [];
for(var i = 0;i<anotherObj.length;i++){
    var id = anotherObj[i].id;
    model.findOne({_id:id},function(err,user){
        if(!err){
            obj.push(user);
            console.log(obj); /* <= it has value */
        }
    })
}

      console.log(obj);  /* <= this is null */
```

Comment: Because the bottom one gets executed before the loop and callback function return the object. So, it's empty (or null) until then.

Comment: You are running into asynchronous issues here. Your `console.log` on the final line is being evaluated before your mongoose method finishes running. Look into callbacks and/or promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your findOne callback runs asynchronous, meaning that your last console.log runs before you push the user to the obj (array).

You would need to call a function after every user in the loop has been fetched. Try the [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) package

Comment: I tried to async package module and I have an issue.  Should I update my post or comment dirrecty on this answer?.

Answer (score 1):

Your query to mongoose are asynchronous. The callbacks will be executed only on the next iteration of the event loop/when the data is available. That is why you see the obj being null.